# Communication between Fragment and DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to make a `Fragment` to show a `Dialog` using [`DialogFragment` API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).

My dialog only has an `EditText` view and I want to pass the string wrote on it back to the `Fragment`.

I'm able to show the dialog from the `Fragment`, but I'm not able to retrieve the string from the input field back to my `Fragment`.

I tried both ways to create a dialog: overwriting the `DialogFragment.onCreateView` method and writing the entire dialog's view and overwriting the `DialogFragment.onCreateDialog` and using the `AlertDialog.Builder` to make it easier to write the buttons behavior.

The Android documentation about dialogs [passing events back to dialog's host](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents) is about host being always an `Activity` and never a `Fragment`. I tried to generalize the behavior for use it on my case, but I cannot.

I tried using the `DialogFragment.onAttach` callback to get the `Activity` reference and use an interface between the `Fragment` and the `DialogFrament` and it works fine, but I cannot retrieve the `Fragment` from the `Activity` to make it work.

Can anybody help with a brief example?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use the [`setTargetFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setTargetFragment%28android.app.Fragment,%20int%29) and [`getTargetFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getTargetFragment%28%29) methods of `Fragment`. You can set your `Fragment` as the target of the `DialogFragment` and then retrieve a reference to it from within the `DialogFragment`.

Comment: It works like a charm. A lot of thanks. The second (and optional) argument for `setTargetFragment` is only needed if I go through the `Activity`, isn't it?

Comment: Wow, the dev docs are pretty misleading here and say you should not do direct fragment communication :https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html yet there is an api for exactly this purpose!

Comment: @Sam I think those docs are talking more about direct communication between different fragments in a multi-pane layout. Consider an activity that shows two fragments in landscape mode but only one of those fragments in portrait mode. If the two fragments directly interacted with one another, things would get messy fast (since you'd have to write extra code that determines whether or not the two fragments are shown at the same time). It would be better to go through the activity (which we know will always exist no matter what) in this case.

Comment: @Sam On the other hand, for this particular question it sounds like the original fragment is tightly coupled with the dialog fragment, so it makes sense to use `setTargetFragment` and `getTargetFragment`.

Comment: Will setTargetFragment() and getTargetFragment method hold true in case of config change where you don't create the dialogFragment but the system restores it for you (if in case the dialog was showing on screen before the config changed)? I don't think so. You will have manually set the target fragment on the restored dialogFragment some how to have the getTargetFragment() working.

Comment: @AKh The target Fragment is retained across configuration changes.  You don't need to call `setTargetFragment` again after everything is restored.

Answer (score 3):

you can use callbacks. just implement a "done" button or something like that in your dialogfragment.

so in your dialogfragment do something like this:

```
protected OnDialogClickedListener callback = null;

public interface OnDialogClickedListener {
    public abstract void onDialogClicked(int position);
}

public void setOnDialogClickedListener(OnDialogClickedListener l){
    callback = l;
}

button.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        callback.onDialogClicked(position);
        dismiss();
    }
});
```

in your activity do something like this:

```
final YourFragment f = YourFragment .newInstance(0);
f.show(ft, "YourFragment ");
f.setOnDialogClickedListener(new OnDialogClickedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDialogClicked(int position) {
        updateText(position);
        f.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Comment: It is easy, but I don't want to modify the `Activity` class because two reasons: first is that it a `PreferenceActivity` and the fragments are loaded from a XML resource definition. And second, it is very coupling to attach the behavior of the relationship between two classes to a third. I already made this using a `PreferenceFragment`, but using a "pure" `Fragment` doesn't work.

Comment: This is exactly how you should NOT do this. You are not respecting the fragment lifecycle. See the accepted answer and the official docs on fragment communication: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html