# Callback function did't trigger when calling from DialogFragment to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, asynccallback

Right now i'm having :-

1) **1** activity which is the main activity that extends from `AppCompactActivity`.

2) **1** `fragment` class that extends from `fragment`, this is the fragment that being called from main activity *(1)* `- ProfileTeacherActivity.java`

3) **1** fragment class that extends from `DialogFragment`, this dialog getting called from fragment *(2)* `- ModalBox.java`

So, basically, this is just a simple flow of execution. At start, the applications showing the `main activity (1)` having drawer that have a few links as example a profile link, when click this link, the application call the `fragment (2)` showing details of profile with one edit button. After clicking edit button, the applications will invoke `DialogFragment (3)` that contains some of `EditText` for editing user's profile.

What i want to achieve is, after editing user's profile and successful saved into database, i tried to send user's data back to `fragment (2)` just to show latest updated info, unfortunately it didn't work.

Here is what i'm tried :

1) Creating Interface inside DialogFragment *(3)* `- ModalBox.java`

```
public class ModalBox extends DialogFragment{

   ....
   public interface EditProfileModalBoxInterface {
     void onFinishEditProfile( HashMap<String, String> dataPassing );
   }
   ...
   ...
}
```

2) Inside DialogFragment also i have `.setPositiveButton` function for `OK` button. `- ModalBox.java`

```
public class ModalBox extends DialogFragment{
   ...       
   ...
   public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
      ...
      builder
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               // At here i'm using retrofit2 http library
               // to do updating stuff
               // and inside success's callback of retrofit2(asynchronous)
               // here i call the below function to send data 
               // dataToSend is a HashMap value
               sendBackResultToParent( dataTosend );
            }
        })
         .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User cancelled the dialog
            }
        });
      .....
   }

   // Function called inside success's callback of retrofit2
   public void sendBackResultToParent( HashMap<String, String> data ) {
      // instantiated interface
      EditProfileModalBoxInterface ls=(EditProfileModalBoxInterface)getTargetFragment();
      // declaring interface's method
      ls.onFinishEditProfile( data );
   }
}
```

3) Finally, i'm implements those interface inside `fragment` *(2)* `- ProfileTeacherActivity.java`

```
public class ProfileTeacherActivity extends Fragment 
       implements ModalBox.EditProfileModalBoxInterface{

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                   ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
       .....
       .....
    }

    // At here the interface's method did't triggered
    @Override
    public void onFinishEditProfile( HashMap dataPassedFromDialog ) {
      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Testing...." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

What i'm confuses right now is, the problem happens only when i called this function `sendBackResultToParent( dataTosend );` inside retrofit2 success's callback, it does triggered when calling outside of it. I'm assumed the async called caused this. If i could use Promise or something like that or is there any workaround on this?

The following existing solutions didn't work in my case :

- [Callback to a Fragment from a DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733304/callback-to-a-fragment-from-a-dialogfragment/13733914#13733914)
- [How to send data from DialogFragment to a Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579590/how-to-send-data-from-dialogfragment-to-a-fragment)
- [Send Data from DialogFragment to Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734432/send-data-from-dialogfragment-to-fragment)

Ask me for more inputs if above use case didn't clear enough or misunderstanding. Thanks for the helps. Regards.

Comment: Not relevant but naming a fragment 'ProfileTeacherActivity' is a bit misleading. :)

Comment: @TalhaMir yeah, that's my silly mistake. ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is a sample `DialogFragment` code used to send message to selected contact. I too required to capture the click event on the `DialogFragment` and redirect.

Ideally to achieve this , this is what needed to be done

- Override the positive/negative button clicks of `AlertDialog.Builder` and do no action
- After this , using `getButton` method mention `AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE` or `AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE` and assign an action

---

```
public class SMSDialogFrag extends DialogFragment {

    private static String one="one";
    private EditText messageContent;
    private AlertDialog dialog;
    private String mobNumber;

    public static SMSDialogFrag showDialog(String mobNumber){
        SMSDialogFrag customDialogFrag=new SMSDialogFrag();
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(one, mobNumber);
        customDialogFrag.setArguments(bundle);
        return customDialogFrag;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sms_dialog, null);

        alertDialogBuilder.setView(view);
        setupUI(view);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("");

        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Do nothing here because we override this button later
            }
        });
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Do nothing here because we override this button later
            }
        });
        dialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        dialog.show();
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                //else dialog stays open. Make sure you have an obvious way to close the dialog especially if you set cancellable to false.
            }
        });
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendMessage();//IN YOUR USE CASE YOU CAN REDIRECT TO YOUR CALLER FRAGMENT

            }
        });

        return dialog;
    }
    void setupUI(View view){
        TextView textViewMob=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.mobNumber);
        messageContent=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.messageContent);
        mobNumber=getArguments().getString(one);
        textViewMob.setText("Send message to : "+mobNumber);
    }
    void sendMessage(){
        if( ! TextUtils.isEmpty(messageContent.getText())){
            try {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                Log.v(Constants.UI_LOG,"Number >>>>>>> "+mobNumber);
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(mobNumber, null, messageContent.getText().toString(), null, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Message Sent!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please enter message to send!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solutions mate, but is there any faulty or misused if we replacing the default action of both `OK` and `Cancel` button?

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali : I didnt find any. Probably you can try to implement and cross check

Answer (score 1):

Consider using eventBus, for example 
[Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)

The usage is very simple. All you need to do is create an evenbus:

```
public static Bus bus = new Bus(ThreadEnforcer.MAIN);  //use Dagger2 to avoid static
```

Then create a receiver method (in fragment 2 in your case):

```
@Subscribe
public void getMessage(String s) {
  Toast.makeText(this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Send you message by calling(from DialigFramgent):

```
bus.post("Hello");
```

And don't forget to register your eventBus inside onCreate method(of your Fragment):

```
bus.register(this);
```

And that is!

Comment: If i'm calling `bus.post("Hello");` inside success callback, subscriber's event never trigger. It does trigger, when i'm calling outside success's callback.

Answer (score 1):

From architectural standpoint, 2 fragments should not directly communicate with one another. Container Activity should be responsible for passing data between it's child fragments. So here's how i would do it:

Implement your interface in the container Activity and just attach your interface implementation in the Activity to the Dialog class and call that interface method when required. Something like this :

```
    public static class ModalBox extends DialogFragment {

    EditProfileModalBoxInterface mListener;

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface EditProfileModalBoxInterface {
     void onFinishEditProfile( HashMap<String, String> dataPassing );
   }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (EditProfileModalBoxInterface) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement EditProfileModalBoxInterface");
        }
    }
}
```

Then call `mListener.onFinishEditProfile(....)` where ever it's required in the `DialogFragment` class.

This way you will receive the result back in your `Activity` class from where you can call your desired fragment's relevant method to pass the results to that fragment.

This whole flow has been described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: Looks like i'm using the wrong concept right now by having two fragments communicating with each others. So, even i'm using `eventBus` like the other guy's is answer, does it not valid or not recommended?

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali Otto will work too. I use it all the time. It's a handy library. Just wanted to explain how google officially recommends it. But using EventBus is completely valid solution to this issue too.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I'm communicate between two fragments directly because want to avoid messing around with main activity, cause i have another fragments to deal with. Anyway, this way does work if i'm calling the `mListener.onFinishEditProfile(....)` outside async success callback of retrofit, unfortunately didn't work when calling inside of it. So weird.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the culprit founds. All the answers mentioned above were right. And my script also actually works, the problem is related with my API `json's` response that did't coming with right structure. In my case, i'm using `retrofit2` with `GSON` converter for parsing into `POJO`. Found the info on log saying about :

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Means that, `GSON` expecting the `json object`, which is my API was returned `JSON array`. Just change the API's structure then all goods to go. Thanks guys for your hard time. Really appreciated, as i'm right now knowing how to deal with `eventBus`, replacing default `OK` and `Cancel` button and the correct way for communicating between fragments.

Comment: yep, always keep your retrofit log on. Don't forget to use Dagger2. Also consider using RxJava with retrofit. Best.