# Why I can't receive data from DialogFragment to Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to send data from DialogFragment to Fragment from which this dialog was created. At target fragment I use this code:

```
val noteData = NoteData()
val bundle = Bundle()
noteData.setTargetFragment(this,0)
noteData.show(fragmentManager!!, noteData.TAG)
```

and I also implemented my interface at fragment:

```
class NotepadScr : Fragment(), NotesInterface
```

At DialogFragment I use this code:

```
private var notesInterface: NotesInterface? = null
 override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        if (context is NotesInterface) {
            notesInterface = context
        } else if (parentFragment is NotesInterface) {
            notesInterface = parentFragment as NotesInterface
        }
    }
```

and send data:

```
notesInterface.archiveNote(recordID!!)
```

I also tried to use `onActivityResult()` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734432/send-data-from-dialogfragment-to-fragment) question:

```
val i = Intent()
i.putExtra("selectedDate", 1122)
targetFragment!!.onActivityResult(1, Activity.RESULT_OK, i)
```

receiving data:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        when(requestCode){
            1->{
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // here the part where I get my selected date from the saved variable in the intent and the displaying it.
                    val bundle = data!!.extras
                    val resultDate = bundle!!.getInt("selectedDate")
                    Timber.i("****************************   %s", resultDate.toString())
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but I didn't manage to receive data :(((

Comment: where are you sending data from Dialog fragment to fragment? Bundle is empty?

Comment: I tried two ways of sending - via interface and via `onActivityResult` and incoming data is empty in both ways

Comment: You do not need interface or onActivityResult to send data from one fragment to another. It can be done using bundle. Can you edit the code and clearly indicate where are you sending it and where are you receiving it.

Comment: Issue can be cornered from that

Comment: @Keshav1234, I would like to receive this data at fragment, and I also shown where I send this data, or you would like to see whole scope?

Comment: are you doing the same as mentioned in Answer?

Answer (score 1):

Data has to be sent as shown below:

```
ReceivingFragment receivingFragment = new ReceivingFragment
Bundle bundle = new Bundle()
bundle.putString(KEY, value to be sent);//Use Int if you want to send int value
receivingFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

This has to be done in receiving fragment

```
String receivingData = getArguments.getString(KEY);
```

Make sure KEY is same in both sending fragment and receiving fragment.

Comment: it looks like sending data between fragment, can I use it for sending data from dialogfragment to parent fragment?

Comment: Yes you can use it to send data between all types of fragments

Comment: but as I understand I will receive this data at onCreate function?

Comment: Yes you will receive in onCreate, onCreateView, onActivityCreated all functions

Comment: but I have to set destination fragment, which I don't see at your answer?