# how to communicate between fragment and dialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have a `fragment` and a `dialogfragment`, I want to communicate between them:
send data from `fragment` to `dialogfragment` and
send data from `dialogfragment`  to `fragment`

I read about `setTargetFragment` and `getTargetFragment` but I couldnot understand how to use them correctly to send/receive data to/from `dialogfragment`.

any help?

Comment: You should have an activity, right? You know how to communicate between activity and fragment, and activity between dialog? then you can communicate between dialog and fragment over activity.

Comment: It would be better understanding if you post your code

Comment: @DevrimTuncer, but I want to learn how to communicate between fragments directly for in case if fragments aren't in the same Activity

Comment: @Masum, I am talking about very simple fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have Communicated from `DialogFragment` to `Fragment` using this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18025715/5993410)

and Communicated from `Fragment` to `dialogFragment` using `setArguments()` and `Bundel`

Answer (score 1):

There's answer for this already. Look at this for [Communication between Fragment and DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026492/communication-between-fragment-and-dialogfragment?rq=1) - if this helps you, you can accept the answer, otherwise you should motivate why your specific problem is different from the one presented in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026492/communication-between-fragment-and-dialogfragment?rq=1).

To see how to use the `setTargetFragment` and `getTargetFragment`, you can look at the [selected answer here] ([How to get data from DialogFragment to a Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025425/how-to-get-data-from-dialogfragment-to-a-fragment)) - specifically, you might find the code helpful for what you want to do.

Comment: I have read that question, But the answers did not explain how to use `setTargetFragment` and `getTargetFragment` methods

Comment: Noted. I have added a reference to an example of how to use these. Please check it out.

Comment: Thanks, This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18025715/5993410) helped me to communicate from `dialogFragment` to `fragment`

Comment: This answer ended up in the review queue; it would be better suited as a comment. An answer is ideally more than references to other answers on StackOverflow.